# 2 images underneath the big one

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

As my previous question has been answered, I am looking to get the 2 images underneath the big one for use in mobile view.

I've tried to remove the float, but that didn't of course not work, well, the images are under it, but not together.

```css
/* center element*/

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.wrapper div {
  display: inline-table;
}


/* Large image */

.big-one {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 70%;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url('http://www.ajax.nl/upload_mm/1/3/9/cid57927_2017-05-03%20Ajax-Olympique%20Lyon%200426.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}


/* Small image */

.small-one {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  width: 30%;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url('http://media.nu.nl/m/0czx8wnaol7a_wd640.jpg/ajax-verslaat-koploper-feyenoord-en-brengt-spanning-terug-in-titelstrijd.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}


/* Small image */

.small-two {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  width: 30%;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url('http://static0.persgroep.net/volkskrant/image/5d4a3648-997a-42c4-b28a-4043136e2e44?width=300');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="big-one">
      <p>
        AJAX DOOR NAAR DE FINALE
      </p>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="small-one">
      <p>
        Ajax wint van Feyenoord
      </p>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="small-two">
      <p>
        LIVE: Ajax komt op 1-0
      </p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

How can I do this? What do I need to do? Here is a screenshot of it without the float: http://image.prntscr.com/image/eb64570782e14dac84ad60a3b8af0cb0.png

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're requesting. You want to place the two smaller pictures under the big one, and you want the two smaller pictures to be side by side? It seems that you already have that. What am missing?

Comment: That's what I want indeed. Well, there is still some space between de small pictures.

Comment: Did you try setting the margin, padding, and border to 0 on your elements? e.g. margin: 0, padding: 0, border: 0.

Comment: That doesn't work sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this fixed by adding 50% to the small-items' width

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px)
.item-big {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-size: cover;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px)
.item-small {
    font-size: 17px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    width: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add 
`dislpay: inline-block;`

to the .small-one and .small-two classes 
this should push the two images together

See if that works...

for the mobile responsiveness, you want to add a media query which may look something like this .....

`@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .small-one,
    .small-two {
        width: 50% 
     }`

if this has not resolved it then I would need to see more HTML and CSS to see the parent element(s)